# How is new application launched on Mac?

Tags: macos, cocoa, process, system, macos-carbon

I am looking for process & a system call which is responsible for starting every new process on Mac. 
I believe it should be something like CreateProcess() and which returns process id of newly created process.(This is a guess)

I am interested in internal details like a flow responsible for launching new application.

Any help is appreciated. Even some references to look after might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally on Mac OS X LaunchD is parent of all the processes. So, LaunchD is launching them. How?? First it [fork()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fork.html) and then [posix_spawn()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/posix_spawn.html).

Answer (score 1):

OS X is a variety of Unix.  New processes are created with the [fork()](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/fork.2.html) system call.  This creates an almost identical copy of the process that makes the call (the difference is that fork returns 0 in the child and the pid of the child in the parent).  It's then normal to use one of the [exec()](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/execve.2.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/2/execve) syscalls in the child to transform the child into a process running a different executable.

**Edit**

Since the question is tagged [Cocoa], I should mention there is a Cocoa class called [NSTask](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTask_Class/Reference/Reference.html) that wraps the above.

Comment: Do you have any Idea which process is responsible for forking and then executing?

Comment: @MachinTosh:  Any process can do fork/exec.

Comment: I understand that any process can fork/exec. But I am interested in finding out the common point of all applications like dock, terminal, itunes? Which process fork & launch them?

Comment: @MachinTosh If you open Activity Monitor (in /Applications/Utilities), and change the dropdown to "All Processes, Hierarchically", you can see which processes started which other processes. In OS X 10.7, launchd is responsible for starting most user processes.

Comment: Okay.. I have tried injecting into LaunchD and then hooked fork and all variations of exec. LaunchD call fork but not exec? Still confused!