# Getting Notified when a process (daemons & applications included) are created in MAC

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, process

I am trying to detect / get notified whenever a new process is created in MAC. The easiest way is to poll all the processes and see if a new process has been launched but that is too time consuming and i wanted to know if i could somehow get some notification whenever a new process is launched using "forked" and "execve". Here is what i have already found :

On how a new process is launched in MAC :

OS X is a variety of Unix. New processes are created with the fork() system call. This creates an almost identical copy of the process that makes the call (the difference is that fork returns 0 in the child and the pid of the child in the parent). It's then normal to use one of the exec() syscalls in the child to transform the child into a process running a different executable.
[How is new application launched on Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7568605/how-is-new-application-launched-on-mac)

On getting the list of all processes through polling

http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/92971-bsd-processes-with-code.html

I have also gone through kAuth kext thing, but it seems beyond my level unless i have some example code for made simple so that i can understand on how to generate the kext and use it in a sample app.
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2127/_index.html

NSWorkspace has a notifier but that is only true for applications and not for all processes.

Any tutorial/ sample code with some basic understanding on how to go about this problem, will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Be sure that this is the level of detail you really want...processes may spawn through `fork()` and `exec...()` functions much, much more frequently than you think.  For example, a single script is started by running a shell process; then, every command in the script will launch a separate process (unless it's a shell built-in command).  Also, each command may *itself* be a script or otherwise have a reason to launch its own sub-processes.  A "simple" command could trigger a very long chain of spawning processes.

Comment: Hmm.... yes you are right on this. However, i need to check it practically and see what compromises i have to make. If the app starts hanging then probably the best approach could be poll the processes and set notification alert for application.

Comment: Hangs are usually resolved using debugging tools; for instance, an older Apple tool named SpinControl was used for this, and now you can probably use Instruments.  (These are part of Xcode.)  You can also attach debuggers to running processes.  The idea is, if you see something that's hanging, you can attach to it at runtime and figure out what it's doing.